# Array resizing. Why cannot I resize the array second time? _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(PUserData)

Tags: c++

I want to resize the array multiple times.It does that the first time but after that, it throws me an error. When I do it the second time, I get an error _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(PUserData). Can someone help me out?

```
int main()
{
    int size = 8;
    int *arr = new int[size];
    arr[1] = 25;
    arr[2] = 30;
    int count = 0;    //to check size
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        count = count + 1;
    }
    cout << count << endl;
    resize(arr, size);
    int new_count = 0;    //to confirm size change
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        new_count = new_count + 1;
    }
    cout << new_count << endl;
    resize(arr, size);
    int new_count2 = 0;    //to confirm size change
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        new_count2 = new_count2 + 1;
    }
    cout << new_count2 << endl;
    return 0;
}
void resize(int *a,int &size)
{
    int newsize = 2 * size;
    int *arr_new = new int[newsize];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)              //copy everything
    {
        arr_new[i] = a[i];
    }
    size = newsize;                 //new value of size
    delete [] a;
    a = arr_new;                    //Pointer pointing to new array
    delete arr_new;
}
```

Comment: You pass `size` by reference but `a` by value... And even if the params were right you point `a` at `arr_new` and then immediately `delete arr_new` (using without the `[]`) - which makes a` invalid.

Comment: `delete arr_new;` -- Wrong form of `delete`.  This should be `delete [] arr_new;`.  Second, why are you deleting the memory you just allocated?

Comment: Thank you for the help! I do not get this. When I do a=arr_new, isnt the 'a' now point to the allocated memory? And I can just delete the arr_new as 'a' also points to the same memory and arr_new not needed. I might sound silly but I am new to coding.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with this code:

```
void resize(int *a,int &size)
{
    [...]

    delete [] a;
    a = arr_new;         //Pointer pointing to new array
    delete arr_new;      // huh????
}
```

The first problem is that you are calling the delete operator twice; the first call deletes the old array (which makes sense), but then you attempt to delete the newly allocated array also (via `delete arr_new`).  How is the caller going to able to use the newly allocated array when `resize()` has already deleted it before it returned?

The second problem is that you set `a` to point to the new array (i.e. `a = arr_new;`) but `a` is a local function-argument that goes out of scope when `resize()` returns, so the calling code will never see its new value.  I think you want this instead:

```
void resize(int * & a,int &size)  // note the & before a!
```

Passing `a` by reference will allow the caller to see `a`'s new value after `resize()` returns.

Comment: And also, arr_new is the local function variable right?

Comment: The pointer `arr_new` is a stack variable, so you don't need to delete it.  The rule to keep in mind is that you should call `delete` exactly once for each call to `new` -- no more, and no less.  `arr_new` is indeed a local variable, since you declare it inside the `resize()` function -- keep in mind that the pointer and the thing it points to are separate things (it's easy to get confused by that)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Passing it by reference worked!